# Map Jackson XML attribute to corresponding JSON element

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

I am using Jackson XmlMapper to deserialize XML to POJO.
Then I am using ObjectMapper to serialize this to JSON.

I'd like to set a JSON key value by using an XML attribute value. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Example XML:

```
<response>
  <label data="someValue" />
</response>
```

needs to map to JSON as:

```
{
  "response" : {
   "label" : "someValue"
   }
}
```

This is what I can get right now:

```
{
  "response" : {
    "label" : {
      "data" : "someValue"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my POJO for the label element:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class LabelObject {

  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "data", isAttribute = true)
  private String data;

  // getter setter
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution on this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've changed the data to make the mapping easier. Maybe someone else has a solution for this problem. I'd like to know also.